# Different answers from chatgpt-api and web interface

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to integrate openai (==0.27.6) into my system, and it works kinda fine, however, the replies I'm getting through the API are totally worse than the answers from the web interface (https://chat.openai.com/chat) .

The way I'm using it with the API (python) is:

```
completitions = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model = 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
    messages=[
        {
            'role': 'user',
            'content': prompt,
        }
    ]
)
```

At this version I'm not using other parameters, like temperature, however, previously with version 0.26.4 I used this:

```
completitions = openai.Completion.create(\
engine='text-davinci-002',
prompt=prompt,
max_tokens=4000,
n=3,
stop=None,
temperature=0.8
)
```

.

Do You guys have any idea how can I set the first example code to give similar answers to the web interface? There' re many parameters that can be set, however, I did not find any documentation about the used values for the web interface.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you're using  engine='text-davinci-002' which is a variation of GPT-3, and the web portal uses GPT-3.5-turbo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the free version of the LLM do not let you use the most recent features. That translates into less accurate and sometimes random answers. To get the better out of GPT you should subscribe to a paid plan. You can subscribe on OpenAI website and then you can add some credit from time to time when you deplete the allocated token quota that depends on the amount that you pay. A normal use would probably cost you about 20USD/month or a little bit more, but it mostly depends on how many prompts you submit to ChatGPT and the quantity of tokens they contain. GPT 3.5 Turbo is free but it is no match for the newest GPT-4 Turbo (currently named GPT-4-1106-preview but shortly it'll be renamed GPT-4 Turbo) and Davinci is noticeably less accurate even than 3.5 Turbo. Then keep the temperature at a low value (0.1 or near that value) if you want answers that are less imaginative.